# Change RVM ubuntu user folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

colleagues.

I renamed my username from **test** to **drobazko**.
Also I renamed a user folder from **/home/test** to **/home/drobazko**. I am developing under Ruby rvm.
And I found out that the **/home/test/** path was mentioned in many rvm files (e.g. /home/drobazko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/mathn/rational.so).
How Can I replace this line in rvm correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it should be as simple as:

```
rvm reinstall all
```